# How to get accurate transformation between two 2D point cloud?

Tags: c++, opencv, 2d, point-clouds

I am using OpenCV ICP algorithm to find Transformation matrix(pose) between one scan 2D data with respect to reference 2D data (CAD DATA) of object.

Reference data:
[image]

Scan data:
[image]
**Approach to filter out points:**

Here for better matching, as shown in below image one imaginary straight points are created(black) in reference data and only points used which are right side of the red line (left sides of points are variable).

filtered reference data:
[image]

Also, in scan data as shown in below image points taken which are right side of the line and imaginary points created. Additionally to match points at the starting (because of convex) in scan data some straight points are created at top (black dots in image) in straight lines(using highest points from that region) and some additional points were removed.

filtered scan data:
[image]

But, OpenCV ICP is not giving accurate result for translation and rotation every time. is there any way to get better transformation matrix or pose for datasets of 2D point cloud? what can be possible approach with or without ICP?

OpenCV ICP: [OpenCV ICP](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d9b/classcv_1_1ppf__match__3d_1_1ICP.html)

Comment: can you link opencv's ICP documentation? ICP needs a good initial coarse registration. Good other techniques for 2d to 2d alignment is keypoint matching (ORB, Sift, Surf, ...) but not for untextured data

Comment: added OpenCV ICP link.

Comment: I dont know whether 3D ICP will work well for 2D data samples. In 2D and 3D, different distance metrics and correspondance strategies could be chosen, like normal-piercing on 3D surfaces or contour-perpendicular-lines (not sure about the real name) in 2D.

Comment: " contour-perpendicular-lines" will this also work if the filtered scan data has linear translation as well? (because most of our scans are have rotational offset as well as X-Y translation offset)

Comment: will only work if some kind of line segments can be associated from the point data. In 3D typically surces are approximated from the neighborhood of each sample. But I don't know whether opencv 3D ICP uses those techniques at all... If only nearest-neighbor point matches are used, I expect the ICP to poorly work in many scenarios. Maybe you find some hints here: https://www.cs.ccu.edu.tw/~tsaic/teaching/summer2009_rt/lecture16.pdf . I didnt find information whether the opencv 3D icp will work well for 2D features.

Comment: ok. what could be another approach for this types of data?

Comment: ICP or template matching (you'll need a lot of templates in all rotations/translations/scalings?), but the ICP implementation might have to be optimized for 2D point/contour data

Comment: I tried to find dual boost icp implementation, but couldnt find code. One executale is here: http://www.vision.cs.rpi.edu/gdbicp/exec/ maybe you want to try it and share experiences.

Comment: After optimization of current ICP implementation, it is working much better. As you mentioned ICP needs good initial pose, I have shifted each scan data near to reference data (filtering one point from scan data and finding probable shift in x according to reference data point(fixed)) and then applied ICP.

Comment: ICP is only giving result on right side of the red line or filtered data. when I applied ICP result to whole scan data it will rotate badly on left side of the scan data. is this because of matching only on right side?

Comment: multiple possible reasons. Can you show the initial registration? Can you visualize the matches? Probably only the right part is used during icp because of some maximumum distance threshold exceedings or similar, Depends on parameters, implementation, etc.

Comment: yes only right side of part is used during ICP while left part will change for every scan data so can not be used. in example image https://ibb.co/CskpRR5, yellow:reference data blue:scan data gray: afterICP result

Comment: also in above image it is bad result on right side.

Comment: can you overlay the result (different colored dots for scan and template)? Can you you overlay the desired result (just rotating and translating the scan data to your needs)? It would be nice to visualize the actually used point correspondences from icp , but not sure whether this is possible.